# Change type of date in html table - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, html-table, echo

I need some help with converting the date to dd/mm/YYYY.

I have this code to display my date in a html table from a mysql database

```
echo "<td>".$zeile['datumFahrt']."</td>";
```

Can I convert it in this line so the format will be dd/mm/YYYY instead of YYYY/mm/dd?

Comment: No im storing it as date. Just need it to display as dd/mm/YYYY

Comment: Okay, with the question update what about using the `date` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php Demo: https://eval.in/635581

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can, first you need to convert it to timestamp and then format it:

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($zeile['datumFahrt']))
```

Comment: `dd/mm` is going to double the day and month output.

Comment: @chris85 Damn you right, edited.

Comment: [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) pairs well with `strtotime`